# Table embedded in a table causing "illegal (beyond boundaries/overlapping)" error in itext

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I use ***table within a table*** when generating the PDF and i get the following error.

```
com.ost.radhaz.struts.survey.action.PreviewSurveyAction caught an exception: com.lowagie.text.BadElementException

com.lowagie.text.BadElementException: ***Adding a cell at the location (4,1) with a colspan of 1 and a rowspan of 1 is illegal (beyond boundaries/overlapping).***
                at com.lowagie.text.Table.addCell(Unknown Source)
                at com.ost.radhaz.struts.survey.action.PreviewSurveyAction.generatePDFDocumentBytes(PreviewSurveyAction.java:882)
                at com.ost.radhaz.struts.survey.action.PreviewSurveyAction.execute(PreviewSurveyAction.java:81)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
                at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
                at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
                at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
                at org.securityfilter.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:182)
                at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
                at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
                at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
                at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
                at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:226)
                at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127)
                at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116)
                at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
                at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I looked up online to find out that iText does not use tables anymore and they suggest using PDFPTable. Apparently for the volume of code that uses table within table in my code, i tried to experiment with just a block of code to see if PDFPtable generates the PDF. Apparently not, I was able to get past the above error, but the PDFPcell that i use to show a particular text chunk does not show up. It shows up as empty. Please advise.

Below is the code i use for PDFPcell

```
Phrase p2 = new Phrase("This is test phrase2", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 30, Font.NORMAL, new Color(255, 0, 0)));
PdfPCell test2 = new PdfPCell(p2);
optable.addCell(test2);
```

This phrase above does not show up in my PDF, it shows up as empty, even though i got to generate the PDF

Please note that in my block of code used above optable is the PDFPtable and that is again embedded in a Table (not PDFPtable).

Comment: When I see my name in somebody's code (my name is Lowagie), I know: that person is using an obsolete version of iText that is unsupported and the chance that this person will receive an answer is very low.

Comment: You need to give us more information. Which version of iText are you using? Please also supply more of your code, what else are you trying to do?

Comment: Table has not been supported since a long time. You may try to add your PdfPTable into another PdfPTable. But the results of adding a PdfPTable into a PdfTable are unpredictable...